# Angular 5 - remove default HTTP headers from request

Tags: javascript, angular, api, http-headers, angular5

The problem here is that whenever I make a http post request to the server.
This is what I see in my network tab

```
Accept: application/json, text/plain, */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en,en-GB;q=0.9
Authorization: Bearer olxyiByY_efkTH_3WavjtTnm0GclhYws....
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Type: application/json
```

I want to remove the 
**Accept: application/json, text/plain, */***
from the request that I make. It is automatically getting set when I make every request.

This is the how I am setting headers

```
public jwt() {

  let headers = new HttpHeaders({ 'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + currentUser.access_token,
  'x-mol-lang': 'en', 'Content-Type': 'application/json'});

  return ({ withCredentials: true, headers: headers, reportProgress: true});
}
```

I am making a service and calling the jwt function for post action.

```
  _this.http.post(_this.url, body, _this.jwtService.jwt()).subscribe();
```

The output that i want in my network tab to show is without **Accept: application/json, text/plain, */* **

Is there any way I can achieve this action?

Comment: Why do you want to do this? It includes `*/*` so it will accept anything, there's no reason for a server to look at that header and reject it with a 406.

Comment: for download api the server throws a 500 error because of it. It creates a problem

Comment: `return this.http.post(_this.url,body {responseType: 'text'})`

Comment: @edrich13 — You should fix the API so it doesn't choke on a perfectly good Accept header.

Comment: try changing the HttpInterceptor.
export class Interceptor implements HttpInterceptor